# Why does the light node not use static peers?

Tags: go-ethereum, nodes

I'm running a light mainnet node. Since she can't find any peers, I added them via the console by taking the enode from [here](https://ethernodes.org/nodes). All the nodes that I added are synchronized, however, even after adding them, the synchronization process of my light node did not go(still looking for peers). Why? Static peers are displayed in the list.

Comment: Are you peers lighting node compatible? I might be wrong but lighting compatibility is not enabled by default on most nodes.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa I am not at all sure that they are compatible with lightning nodes. How can I find out about compatibility?

Comment: [See running a light server here](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/fundamentals/les#running-light-client). You probably need to ask from the peer host.